# how to create DateAndTime picker in swift 4 which so that user is able to select date and time both

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have implemented the iOS date and time picker is my project like this

[image]

but the problem here is that is user want to select year and month then there is no option. how to solve this I can not find any library.

I want a date and time picker from which user can select date year, month,day and time hh:mm ?

Comment: That's not supported by `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: so how I solve this problem can u suggest any library

Comment: Maybe have two date pickers. One for the full date and one for the full time.

Comment: I think about it if I don't find any other way

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UIPicker class to implement your own date an time picker. It would have year, month, day, hour, minute, and possibly AM/PM sections. You'd need to build some intelligence around changing the available days depending on the month (different months have different numbers of days, and on leap years February has a different number of days than on other years.)

Comment: The challenge is fitting that many column inside one picker view.

Comment: True. You'd have to make it pretty compact.